# javascript/angular 4 property is undefined after interval tries to get value

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to build an timer, but it is not working.
What I do is I have a button which starts the timer. It sets the begin time and after that start an interval to count on screen. But the function which is called by the interval fails because the beginning time is undefined. I debuged to see if the beginning time is being set, and it is. But when it is called through the interval it is undefined.

Here is my code
Some properties

```
 timeBegan = new Date();
  started = null;
```

the start function

```
start() {
this.timeBegan = new Date();
document.getElementById('ticker').innerHTML = '00:00:00.000';

this.started = setInterval(this.clockRunning, 10);
  }
```

the clockrunning function

```
public clockRunning() {
const currentTime = new Date();
console.log(this.timeBegan);
console.log(currentTime.getTime());
const timeElapsed = new Date(currentTime.getTime() - this.timeBegan.getTime());
const hour = timeElapsed.getUTCHours();
const min = timeElapsed.getUTCMinutes();
const sec = timeElapsed.getUTCSeconds();
const ms = timeElapsed.getUTCMilliseconds();

console.log(currentTime.getSeconds());
console.log(this.timeBegan);
document.getElementById('ticker').innerHTML =
    (hour > 9 ? hour : '0' + hour) + ':' +
    (min > 9 ? min : '0' + min) + ':' +
    (sec > 9 ? sec : '0' + sec) + '.' +
    (ms > 999 ? ms : ms > 9 ? '0' + ms : '000' + ms);


 }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use it like this in start function:

```
this.started = setInterval(this.clockRunning.bind(this), 10);
```

or:

```
this.started = setInterval(function(e){
      this.clockRunning();
}.bind(this), 10);
```

It will definitely solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

It is not working because you are referencing:

```
this.timeBegan
```

However, "this" is not refering to the "this" you want it to refer to. "this" is the function defined in setInterval. This is because ES5 functions have their own "this".

You could try using an ES6 function which will prob use the "this" you want.

Alternatively, force "this" within your function to refer to the "this" you want by doing:

```
this.clockRunning = this.clockRunning.bind(this)
```

This means that the "this" within clockRunning will ALWAYS be the "this" passed to bind(). Make sure you pass the right "this" to bind :) viz the "this" that has the timeBegan property.